# Why Promise.resolve().then() is delayed?

Tags: javascript, promise

I don't understand why resoved Promise delay `.then()` argument call?

example:

```
var myPromise = Promise.resolve();
console.log(myPromise);
myPromise.then(()=>console.log('a'));
console.log('b');
```

console return:

```
> Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }
> "b"
> "a"
```

If `myPromise` is fulfilled, why `.then()` don't call imediatly resolve function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because, by specification, promises call their resolve handler AFTER the current thread of execution unwinds and finishes back to "platform code".  That guarantees that they are always called asynchronously.

So, thus you see the `console.log('b')` first as that thread of execution finishes and then the resolve handler is called where you see the `console.log('a')`.

From the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/):

> 2.2.4 onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution
>   context stack contains only platform code. [3.1].

And, here's note [3.1]:

> Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise
>   implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that
>   onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event
>   loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be
>   implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as setTimeout or
>   setImmediate, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as
>   MutationObserver or process.nextTick. Since the promise implementation
>   is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling
>   queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.

This is done to provide consistent execution order so no matter when the promise is resolved (synchronously or asynchronously), the `then()` handlers are always called in the same timing relative to other code.  Since many promises are resolved asynchronously, the only way to make a given promise consistent no matter how it is resolved is to make them always call their `.then()` handlers asynchronously.

Answer (score 6):

jfriend00's answer is correct. Allow me to elaborate on why. Let's say I got `myPromise` from somewhere. I don't know it's just a `Promise.resolve`, it *might* resolve asynchronously, and it might not.

```
myPromise.then(function(){
     console.log("a");
});
console.log("b");
```

If the asynchronousity guarantee didn't exist - that would *sometimes* log `a b` and sometimes `b a`. This is a race condition, and is a [terrible thing to have](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony). Promises are not susceptible to this problem by design - and execution order is *always* guaranteed in new promises implementations and native promises in particular.

The actual implementation of running new jobs is [via Job Queues](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues). `then` enqueues a job to the job queue in the handler, and job queues are run after code is ready - this is specified [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-initialization).