# Await equivalent of 'Promise.resolve().then()'?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm familiar with Promises, but have inherited some rather unusual code that, rather than making a `new Promise()`, uses the following:

```
Promise.resolve().then(
  function() {
    // Do useful things
  }
)
```

From my research, this is a [weird version of setImmediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225687/why-promise-resolve-then-is-delayed) - ie, run the following function on the next tick.

**What would be the `await` version of this?**

Comment: I believe it is `(async function(){})()` but I'm not sure so I'm leaving this as comment

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There may be two different reasons for the `Promise.resolve()`. You touched on one of them:

### Defer until the end of the current run of the JS  event loop

Here the obvious answer is `await Promise.resolve();`.

`await undefined` does the same thing implicitly, but why not be explicit?

### Singular error handling

`Promise.resolve()` is also often seen at the head of a promise chain for singular error handling:

```js
const doSomething = x => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(x), 1000));

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => doSomething(""())) // bug!
.then(() => doSomething("else"))
.catch(e => console.log("Got " + e)); // Got TypeError: "" is not a function
```

Without it, the first step may throw an exception instead, which may be unexpected!

```js
const doSomething = x => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(x), 1000));

doSomething(""()) // bug!
.then(() => doSomething("else"))
.catch(e => console.log("Got " + e)); // uncaught!
```

Here the answer is: **you no longer need the `Promise.resolve()` prologue with async/await.**

`async` functions implicitly catch synchronous exceptions and return a rejected promise instead, guaranteeing singular error handling and a promise return value:

```js
const doSomething = x => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(x), 1000));

(async () => {
  await doSomething(""()); // bug!
  await doSomething("else");
})().catch(e => console.log("Got " + e)); // Got TypeError: "" is not a function
```

Not only is this a nice invariant and less to type, unlike the `Promise.resolve()` kludge, it actually still calls `doSomething` synchronously:

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log("doSomething() called");
  ""() // bug!
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(x), 1000));
}

(async () => {
  await doSomething();
  await doSomething("else");
})().catch(e => console.log("Got " + e)); // Got TypeError: "" is not a function

console.log("here");
```

This would be pretty hard to pull off any other way. Another reason async/await is great!

Comment: Does 'end of the current run' mean end of the current tick?

Comment: @mikemaccana Yes, the end of the current run of the [JS event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), i.e. the end of the [currently running task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#currently-running-task), or "tick" in Node.js terms.

Comment: "_`await undefined` does the same thing (as `await Promise.resolve()`) implicitly_"

I just did make other observations: `await undefined` does _not_ interrupt the synchronous execution. See https://jsbin.com/bidonij/edit?js,console

Comment: @ulrichb `await` *always* interrupts synchronous execution, as [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/nx0Lfyeu/) shows. Your codepen shows something else, which is when racing with another promise chain, `await Promise.resolve()` apparently queues one additional micro task compared to `await undefined`. Good to know.

Answer (score 6):

Just `await` something.

If you give `await` an expression which is not a promise, it will behave like

```
await Promise.resolve(<nonPromiseExpression>)
```

So `await undefined` will cause the rest of the async function to be executed asynchronously. Take these two implementations of `setImmediate` as an example:

```js
var setImmediate = function (fn) {
  Promise.resolve().then(fn);
};

console.log('A');
setImmediate(function () {
  console.log('E');
});
console.log('B');

setImmediate = async function (fn) {
  await undefined;
  fn();
};

console.log('C');
setImmediate(function () {
  console.log('F');
});
console.log('D');
```

Comment: Could this answer be reduced to `await undefined;`?

Answer (score 5):

> I have inherited some rather unusual code that, rather than making a `new Promise()` uses a `Promise.resolve().then(…)`. From my research, this is a weird version of setImmediate - ie, run the following function on the next tick.

That's a side-effect, but probably not the intended purpose of this construct. The main point is that the "useful code" in the `then` callback is `throw`-safe and can easily `return` plain values and promises alike, starting a usual promise chain. It *could* have been written with `new Promise` as well, but that would have required to use a `resolve` call instead of the usual `return`.

> What would be the `await` version of this?

Literally, `await Promise.resolve();` (which could be shortened to the equivalent `await undefined;` statement). However, if it was done for the purposes of error handling alone (which is likely), just omit it. `async function`s will transform exceptions into rejections by default.

Comment: When I try using `await;`, both typescript and eslint complains in the vscode editor: `Parsing error: Unexpected token (32:7) eslint` and `Expression expected. ts(1109)`. Are you sure that is valid?

Comment: @micnil Ah, no it's not. This works with `yield` but not with `await`. Thanks for the heads up!